# setting up serial port and writing to following online tutorials

Tags: c++, winapi, console

i was reading some online tutorials on how to send a few bytes via the com port.
i solved some problems, but i get stuck on:

```
WriteFile(hSerial, bytes_to_send, 5, &bytes_written, NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d bytes written\n", bytes_written);
```

the code will output:
- Opening serial port...OK
- Sending bytes...0 bytes written

i would like to send some bytes via the com port to the uart on the micro controller.
this code looks very useful for what i need to do.

the code i'm using:

```
//
// serial.c / serial.cpp
// A simple serial port writing example
// Written by Ted Burke - last updated 13-2-2013
//
// To compile with MinGW:
//
//      gcc -o serial.exe serial.c
//
// To compile with cl, the Microsoft compiler:
//
//      cl serial.cpp
//
// To run:
//
//      serial.exe
//

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Define the five bytes to send ("hello")
    char bytes_to_send[5];
    bytes_to_send[0] = 104;
    bytes_to_send[1] = 101;
    bytes_to_send[2] = 108;
    bytes_to_send[3] = 108;
    bytes_to_send[4] = 111;

    // Declare variables and structures
    HANDLE hSerial;
    DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = {0};

    TCHAR *pcCommPort = TEXT("COM1");

    // Open the highest available serial port number
    fprintf(stderr, "Opening serial port...");

    //hSerial = CreateFile( ComPortName, 
 //                     GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,      
    //        0,
 //                     NULL,
 //                     OPEN_EXISTING,                     
 //                     FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,              
    //        NULL); 


    hSerial = CreateFile(
                pcCommPort, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );

    if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
            return 1;
    }
    else fprintf(stderr, "OK\n");

    // Set device parameters (38400 baud, 1 start bit,
    // 1 stop bit, no parity)
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    if (GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error getting device state\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_38400;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
    if(SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting device parameters\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }

    // Set COM port timeout settings
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    if(SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting timeouts\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }

    // Send specified text (remaining command line arguments)
    DWORD bytes_written, total_bytes_written = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "Sending bytes...");



    if(!WriteFile(hSerial, bytes_to_send, 5, &bytes_written, NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }   
    fprintf(stderr, "%d bytes written\n", bytes_written);

    // Close serial port
    fprintf(stderr, "Closing serial port...");
    if (CloseHandle(hSerial) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "OK\n");

    // exit normally
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

further editing the code using GetLastError() results in:

```
OVERLAPPED o;
     std::memset(&o, 0, sizeof(o));

     o.Offset = FILE_WRITE_TO_END_OF_FILE;
     o.OffsetHigh = -1;

if(!WriteFile(hSerial, bytes_to_send, 5, &bytes_written, &o))
    {
        //DWORD WINAPI GetLastError(void);
        //wprintf(L"Format message failed with 0x%x\n", GetLastError()); // 0x3e3 
        printf("Error number: %ld\n", GetLastError()); 995 (0x3E3)
        // The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }   
    fprintf(stderr, "%d bytes written\n", bytes_written);
```

hyperterminal, can detect my app and want me to close it.

regards and thank you.

Comment: What does [`WriteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) return? If it returns `FALSE` have you [checked what error you have](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: i have put a breakpoint on: `fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");`, but i can't see the error.

Comment: Beware of connecting a RS-232 port to MIDI equipment; they use different signaling levels.

Comment: Never use `GetCommState` (except for debugging).  Set the fields you need, leave the rest at zero.  Any field that matters is worth setting yourself, not inheriting from who-really-knows-what software that previously used the port.  Unless you enjoy troubleshooting seemingly random failure.

Comment: And you can use any baud rate just with `dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = 31250;`  The common baud rate constants are just macros that expand reflexively to the numeric baud rate.

Comment: It is the baudrate for MIDI, a standard created by an industry group that sold hardware.  Of course they didn't pick a baudrate that you can easily select on a standard PC, that's not good for business.  You'll have to go shopping.  It doesn't cost much anymore, a USB adapter costs thirty bucks.

Comment: ´wprintf(L"Format message failed with 0x%x\n", GetLastError());´ like this it returns this: ´0x3e3´, does this help?

Comment: in release mode, i get:´ Opening serial port...OK
Sending bytes...0 bytes written
Closing serial port...OK´, the same output.

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: there is a max232 ic on the board.

Comment: Hans Passant: it's just for ease of use, to not mes with the pic micro settings and some debugging.

Comment: Of course you can't see the error, you *don't fetch the error*! You need to call [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to actually *get* the error code. Then check [the system error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see what error you have, or use [`FormatMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a printable string.

Comment: One last thing: You need to call `GetLastError` *right after the function that failed*, otherwise other calls may change the error code.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? How? I have the same one. Thanks